# Auto rotating code works on iPhone but not on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, autorotate

This is the code that only works on the iphone.
I am making a universal app that runs on both devices, so it it the identical app.

```
**//Automatically rotates the view to landscape
    let orientation: UIDeviceOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
    //If landscape right the rotate right
    if orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft
    {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations:
            {
                () -> Void in
                let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue
                UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
        })


    }
    else
    {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations:
            {
                () -> Void in
                let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
                UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
        })

    }**
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possibility for you to check...

In the project's settings, under the General tab for a build target, there's the Deployment Info section where you select the "Devices" option (that you probably have on "Universal"). Below that is the Device Orientation selection. There's one, um, interesting feature here.

If you check some orientations when Devices is on Universal, it only applies the setting to the iPhone version. If you toggle the Devices selection to iPad, the options will likely be different. What you need to do is switch the selection to iPhone, apply the orientations you want there, switch it to iPad, apply orientations again, and then finally set Devices to Universal.

I have a hunch (not tested with your code) that if you try to apply an orientation that is not supported here, your code will do nothing.